# The use of 放在 in a sentence

Tags: grammar, word

I was looking at this sentence 我把雪糖放在这杯咖啡里 and was wondering if it would be grammatically sound to say 我放在这杯咖啡雪糖 to mean the same thing.

Comment: 我放在这杯咖啡雪糖 is wrong. In this case, you have to use 把...structure just like your first example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The first sentence "我把雪糖放在这杯咖啡里" is grammatically correct

[我 - subject (I)]

[把 - disposal marker that dispose the following object ]

[砂糖 - object (sugar)]

[放 - verb (put)]

[在( ~ )里 - preposition (into)]

[在(这杯咖啡)里 - relative phrase indicates location (into this cup of coffee)]

> The second sentence "我放在这杯咖啡(砂糖)" is grammatically incorrect.

It should be: [我放 + (object)+  在这杯咖啡里] = "我放(砂糖)在这杯咖啡里"

'砂糖'(object) is wrongly placed after the (relative phrase that indicate location) '这杯咖啡里'. That created a '[这杯咖啡 (n)]+[砂糖 (n)] situation'

it also missed the '里' in the preposition '在 ~ 里'

> to put the object '砂糖' after  '这杯咖啡' , you cannot use the disposal  marker '把'
>
> The correct form is "我在这杯咖啡里放入砂糖"

我(subject)

在( ~ )里(preposition)

在(这杯咖啡)里 (relative phrase- indicate location)

放入 (verb)

砂糖 (object)

Comment: 3rd line: "depositive"?  users suggest "dispositive", "dispose"

Comment: The usual term in English is "[disposal marker](http://www.ling.sinica.edu.tw/files/publication/j2009_1_03_0074.pdf)"

Comment: This is from https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Using_%22ba%22_sentences ... How would you say this without the 把 construction? You might try this:

放 书 在 桌子 上 。
Fàng shū zài zhuōzi shàng.
The problem is that the above Chinese sentence is not grammatical. You can't put an object right after a verb, and then put other modifiers of the verb after the object. Here are other examples of how to successfully use 把 and 放 in the same sentence. So I am guessing  "我放(砂糖)在这杯咖啡里" is incorrect.

Comment: 我(I) 放(put) 砂糖(sugar) 在(into) 这杯咖啡里(this cup of coffee) is [(subject)+(verb)+(objective) + (relative phrase)]  I don't see anything wrong with that

Comment: "I put vegetable into the pot " literally mean "我放蔬菜入锅中" ;  on the other hand "我把蔬菜放入锅中  literally mean "I take the vegetable and put it into the pot" using 把 emphasize what I am doing with the vegetable; while "我放蔬菜入锅中" emphasize what I put into the pot. >"我在这杯咖啡里把砂糖放入" sounds like "I am in the cup of coffee"

Answer (score 1):

fronting object (雪?)糖 (食糖）is possible: 我食糖放在这杯咖啡里, grammar topic: prepositions（介词）, 在，e.g. ＂图解基础汉语语法＂介词（１）：**在**、到、给（一）在＂在＂主要引出时间和地点１。在动词前 格式 在＋时间＋做什么 在＋哪儿＋做什么 Attention ＂在＋时间＋做什么＂格式中＂在＂常省略 玛丽是在到了北京以后才开始学汉语的。 玛丽在图书馆看书。**２。在动词后** 格式 动词＋在＋时间 动词＋在＋地方 玛丽出生在冬天 杯子放在桌子上Attention 只有部分动词可以用在＂动词＋在＋时间＂格式中，双音节动词主要有＂出生、发生、出现＂等，单音节动词主要有＂定、改、排、放＂等。**More examples for  在动词后** ＂现代汉语虚词词典＂（w/o 把）大衣搭在臂上，手里提着书包，孩子留在［了］姥姥家了，钉在墙上，挂在树上、两手按在桌子上，永远的惭愧和感谢留在我心里（朱自清），有些爱花的人，大都只是将花栽在盆里，一盆盆搁在架上；架子横放在院子里（朱自清）